# Improper integral on $D_r$

Tags: real-analysis

I want to calculate $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{D_r} {{x+1} \over {y}} \ dx \ dy$$  with $D_r=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2\ge r^2,0\le x\le y^2,r\le y \le 1 \}$.
Is it an improper integral ?

Answer (score 0):

If you sketch the area you see that it's not conclude the circle then
$$\int_r^1\int_{\sqrt{x}}^\infty\dfrac{x+1}{y}dydx=\int_r^1\int_{-\infty}^{-\sqrt{x}}\dfrac{x+1}{y}dydx=\infty$$

**Edit:**

After changing in the post, we see that the circle meets the parabola in a point with $x_0=\sqrt{r^2+\dfrac{1}{4}}-\dfrac{1}{2}$, so the integral will be
$$\int _0^{\sqrt{r^2+\dfrac{1}{4}}-\dfrac{1}{2}}\int _{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}^1\frac{x+1}{y}dydx+\int _{\sqrt{r^2+\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{1}{2}}^1\int _{\sqrt{x}}^1\frac{x+1}{y}dydx$$
practically when $r\to0^+$ this integral is the same as 
$$\int_0^1\int_{\sqrt{x}}^1\frac{x+1}{y}dydx=\color{blue}{\dfrac58}$$
and the first part will be vanish, since $x_0=\sqrt{r^2+\dfrac{1}{4}}-\dfrac{1}{2}\to0$.

Comment: there was an error in the text: y is between r and 1

Comment: I saw your changes and update the answer!